# How to detect ALT (Menu) button keydown on global page level in a WinRT app

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, keydown

I use following code to detect all key events in a WinRT app page:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
...

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
  //Handle key event
}
```

But the Alt (Menu in the VirtualKey enumeration) key does not trigger the CoreWindow.KeyDown event. It does also block any other key to trigger the event while pressed.

Anyone know how to detect the Alt keydown event on a global page level in a WinRT app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug [Unexpected behavior in Windows.Core.UI.CorePhysicalKeyStatus.IsMenuKeyDown](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9bebfb0a-7637-400e-8bda-e55620091407/unexpected-behavior-in-windowscoreuicorephysicalkeystatusismenukeydown).

Though I tried `Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated`, it handles `Alt` key.