# How to find out what character the user pressed in a WinRT app if the character not is included in the Virtual key enums?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

**In short:**

How can I in a world-wide Windows Store app correctly validate on a page if a user pressed one of the keys not included in the VirtualKey Enum list? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx) In my case it is the “,”  and “´” characters I need to handle.

**Detailed:**

I am stucked on how to validate keyboard input from different keyboard layouts correctly in my Windows Store app. There are many posts here about it but noone seems to have an answer.

My app accepts keyboard input on a page (without any textboxes) to validate key sequences.
I have hooked up on Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated event to handle all inputs (see: [How to detect ALT (Menu) button keydown on global page level in a WinRT app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186280/how-to-detect-alt-menu-button-keydown-on-global-page-level-in-a-winrt-app)). As you can see in the code example below I use the AcceleratorKeyEventArgs to find out what VirtualKey is pressed.

And it works brilliant well on my Swedish keyboard and from my understanding it will also work as good for all users around the world because the virtualkeys is the same no matter keybord layout or language settings.

Now my problem:

The Windows.System.VirtualKey enum just have 165 buttons defined and two of the keys I need to validate is not included: "," and "´".

When I use a Eng/Swe keyboard setting pressing "´" key the AcceleratorKeyEventArgs.VirtualKey gives me "219"

And when i use a Eng/US keybord setting pressing the "´" key (i checked in notepad what key will generate a "´", the AcceleratorKeyEventArgs.VirtualKey gives me "188".

Same problem is described here I think:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c3099f93-6365-4254-abba-d512b05f2edd/winrt-equivalent-for-mapvirtualkey

I tested to extend the VirtualKey enum with more characters by using this tecnique:
http://useranswer.com/answer/how-to-convert-a-virtualkey-to-a-char-for-non-us-keyboard-layouts-in-winrt/
But the Windows App Certification Kit failed with "*API MapVirtualKeyA in user32.dll is not supported for this application type*"

Example code:

```
public PractisePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated +=Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
        _vm = (PractisePageVm)DataContext;

    }


private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.EventType)
        {
            case CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.SystemKeyUp:
            case CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyUp:
                _vm.HandleKeyUp(args.VirtualKey);
                break;
            case CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.SystemKeyDown:
            case CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyDown:
                if (args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown == false)
                {
                    _vm.HandleKeyDown(args.VirtualKey);
                }
                break;
        }
        args.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just not how virtual keys work.  They represent a specific key on a keyboard and have a code that's independent of the keyboard layout and the user's language.  What character they produce however greatly depends on the active keyboard layout, the state of the modifier keys (Alt, Ctrl, Shift) and whether any dead keys were pressed earlier.  Trying to figure this out by yourself will lead to tears, not in the least because some characters are just not available on a keyboard layout in a far-flung country.  The virtual key is however always present.

For accelerator keys, you never care about that character.  You only care about the virtual key code and the modifier key state.  So if you define, say, Alt+A as an accelerator then everybody in the whole world will press the key located to the right of the capslock key.  Do note that you *will* have a documentation problem, that key isn't labeled "A" everywhere.  But that's just part of the normal localization effort.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Are you are saying that I can not even use the above code to check for characters included in the virtualkey enum list like the character A: if args.virtualkey==VirtualKey.A?

And for my original question. Is there no way for me to find out if a user typed a "," or "´"? A keybord tutor app would for example want to define a sentence and then react on each key pressed by the user and inform if it was correct character or not.

Comment: VirtualKey.A identifies the key, not character A.  It will produce a very different character on, say, a Chinese machine.  A keyboard tutor app should only ever care about characters.  So should always use the CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event and **not** use KeyDown or virtual keys.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think I have to throw my app in the garbage, but atleast I learnt how to handle keyboard input :)